# Navigation Drawer header image not clickable

Tags: android

The imageview is not clickable . how do i make it clickable its located inside the drawer for showing a profile pic .

```
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    CircleImageView imageView = (CircleImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(DashboardMain.this, "image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: please check the below link, hope this will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31716034/android-onclick-for-navigation-drawer-header-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
CircleImageView mImgView= (CircleImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
```

if you have multiple headers

```
navigationView.getHeaderCount()
```

Ref:https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190226#c31

Answer (score 1):

```
    View headerLayout = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

    CircleImageView imageView = (CircleImageView)headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```