# Make my navigation drawer header clickable ( make image view clickable)

Tags: android, header, navigation

i have a problem in my code the app doesn't perform clickable image and doesn't show a Toast message when i tap it

i have already tried this link but didn't worked
[OnClick for navigation drawer header not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31716034/onclick-for-navigation-drawer-header-not-working/34327715#34327715)

This is my main activity:

```
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) 
    findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

     View headerview = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
     ImageView imageButton = (ImageView) 
     headerview.findViewById(R.id.login);

    LinearLayout header = (LinearLayout) 
    headerview.findViewById(R.id.header);
     header.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello 
     Javatpoint",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
     });
```

This is my header xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
android:background="@color/splashBackground"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:id="@+id/header"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/nav_header_desc"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/realprolinklogo" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:text="REAL PROLINK"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance"
        android:textColor="@color/splashText"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />




</LinearLayout>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="62dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/loginsignup"/>




  </LinearLayout>
```

This is my nav-view:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
 tools:openDrawer="start">

  <include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main2"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main2_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

No error message

But expected result didn't came

Comment: Hey Ahsan, can you post your nav_view layout as well. I had a similar issue and I was able to fix it. Try putting your LinearLayout header inside of the nav_view instead of having a separate layout

Comment: added @YunusKulyyev

Comment: Why do you set the listener to the layout? Set it to `imageButton`.

Comment: @forpas i changed it to image button but still it doesn't show toast message

Comment: ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) headerview.findViewById(R.id.login);

Comment: I did not mean that. I mean: instead of `header.setOnClickListener(...` set `imageButton.setOnClickListener(...`

Comment: @forpas actually i followed the same code as 
This link -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31716034/onclick-for-navigation-drawer-header-not-working/34327715#34327715
can you take a look if this is right?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so, instead of including your header layout to nav_view, try the follwoing:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
 tools:openDrawer="start">

  <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
android:background="@color/splashBackground"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:id="@+id/header"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/nav_header_desc"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/realprolinklogo" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:text="REAL PROLINK"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance"
        android:textColor="@color/splashText"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />




</LinearLayout>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="62dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/loginsignup"/>




  </LinearLayout>

  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main2"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main2_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```